# Not understanding the concept of abrogation (naskh)

Tags: quran

Salamo'alaikom, I've read some answers about naskh and it seems that it is the case of surat al Ahzab, which was as long as surat al Baqara but then some verses were abrogated. I'm not understanding this thing in terms of preservation of Quran. What does it mean that Quran has been preserved till now when there is this concept of naskh?  Can someone clarify as I don't understand it quite well?

Answer (score 1):

Qur'an is the word of Allah (ﷻ) and it is what He decides it to be. If He decides to abrogate a portion, that doesn't mean that portion is "missing" because He does not intend it to be part of the Book ultimately. So it doesn't contradict preservation nor does it count as corruption.

Once the Qur'an was all revealed and Angel Jibra'il (peace be upon him) and the Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) reviewed it and it was understood that this is going to be the Qur'an with us forever now until the end of time, the Qur'an has not changed one bit. No accidental changes, no intentional changes could ever touch the Qur'an. It is guarded by Allah (ﷻ).

Compare this to other books in which changes were made by humans that were not authorized by God, in which portions were added or deleted when God did not authorize it. So these have truly been changed. (See [Sources of Change in Previous Books](https://veiledink.wordpress.com/2016/12/29/sources-of-change-in-previous-books/))

Let me know if further clarification is needed. Wa Alaikum As Salam.

Comment: Salamo3alaykom, firstly jazaka Allah for your answers. Regarding this topic, you're saying that basically these changes occurred only during the 23-year-lasting revelation by Allah's wisdom and not by mistake (audhubillah) and after the revelation has ended then there haven't been any changes ever since, correct? So preservation is to be meant from the end of the revelation untill now, and 1400 years have passed more or less. Is it what you mean?

Comment: So the moral is that Quran has been changed only during the revelation because Allah wanted to make things easier or harder depending on the behaviour of the Muslims, and not after, correct?

Comment: Yes, per my understanding, this is correct.

Comment: Ok, but when you say that Jibreel (Alayhi Salam) and Muhammad (Salla Allah wa'alayhi wa sallam) "reviewed it", what do you mean exactly with that? Did Allah say to Jibreel to say to Muhammad (salla Allah wa'alayhi wa sallam) that this Quran is going to be in last form or something similar? P.S If you ever will, please answer this question too because no one has answered yet https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/55659/difference-between-%d8%b5%d9%8e%d9%84%d9%91%d9%90-and-%d8%a8%d9%8e%d8%a7%d8%b1%d9%90%d9%83%d9%92-after-the-tashahhud

Comment: It means Jibra'il recited the Qur'an to the Prophet start to finish. From hadith: (the Prophet) told her [Fatima RA]: "Gabriel used to recite the Qur'an to me once a year and for this year it was twice and so I perceived that my death had drawn near" ( https://sunnah.com/muslim/44/144 ).

Comment: Jazaka Allah o khayran sister