# Possible translation mistake of islamqa

Tags: arabic, language

Salamo3alaykom, in this answer in IslamQa I've may have found a translation after the tashahhud, translating at the beginning as "O Allah send prayers..." but Allah does NOT send prayers, rather He sends blessings. It translates "barik" as "sending blessings", but It translates "salli" as sending prayers. What does it exactly mean by sending prayers from the part of Allah? Allah does NOT pray because he is Allah.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/98031

Can someone clarify please?

Answer (score 1):

You (and they) are correct that "Barik" means "send blessings". And they are also correct in saying that "Salli" means "send prayers", but our understanding of it makes the difference.

Is read in Arabic:

> **Allaahumma salli ‘ala** Muhammad wa ‘ala aali Muhammad kama salayta ‘ala aali Ibraaheem, wa baarik ‘ala Muhammad wa ‘ala aali Muhammad kama baarakta ‘ala aali Ibraaheem fi’l-aalameen, innaka hameedun majeed

Its translation:

> **O Allaah, send prayers** upon Muhammad and the family of Muhammad, and send blessings upon Muhammad and the family of Muhammad, as You sent prayers and blessings upon Ibraaheem and the family of Ibraaheem among the nations; You are indeed Worthy of Praise, Full of Glory.

The scholars interpreted **the praying** to mean:

From Allah:

- It would mean peace — "Allah sends His peace (upon)..."

From Angels:

- It would mean Istighfar (asking forgiveness from Allah for...)

From people:

- It would mean making Du'a in their prayers for...

But take into consideration that this specific praying, which is related to the Prophet (Peace Be Upon Him), is more specified than peace or else we would pray for any other Muslim if it always meant peace.

As for the interpretation of:

> - اللهم صلي على سيدنا محمد
> - Allaahumma Salli ‘ala Muhammad
> - O Allaah, send prayers upon Muhammad

It means that we are asking Allah to praise him (the prophet Muhammad) in the Upper Skies among the Angles.

---

[Source](https://ar.islamway.net/article/62132/-14-%D8%AA%D8%AF%D8%A8%D8%B1-%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D8%B4%D9%87%D8%AF)

Comment: Salamo3alaykom, so it means that we ask Allah to send OUR prayers for him 3alayhi salat wa sallam, doesn't it?

Comment: Wa Alaykumu As-Salam. No, this is not right. What we exactly do by saying "O Allaah, send prayers..." that we ask Allah to send **His** compliments among Angles in the Upper Skies.

Comment: I've not understood yet, when you say "we ask Allah to send His compliments aming Angels in the Upper skies" you're not mentioning Muhammad ﷺ.

Comment: If I had to continue the interpretation of the saying, I would come to that part. It would be: "We ask Allah to send His compliments among Angles in the Upper Skies **upon the prophet Muhammad**." OR  "We ask Allah to praise **the prophet Muhammad** in the Upper Skies among the Angles." Both interpretations indicate the same meaning, but I prefer the latter as the former has been stated, in the first place, as other wording of the second one.